# Any example proving microtask is executed before rendering?

Tags: javascript, event-loop, html-rendering

I saw several articles says that **render steps are after microtasks.**

I test it with this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>test</p>
  <script>
const p = document.querySelector('p');
p.textContent = 'text';
Promise.resolve().then(function microtask() {
  debugger;
  p.textContent = 'Promise';
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code seems show that the UI is **re-rendered before the microtask run**.

Am i think about it wrong? Is there any good example shows that rendering is after microtask run ?

Comment: It doesn't really matter when the DOM is rendered. That you cannot observe it is the whole point allowing browsers to defer it, not re-rendering after every single change.

Comment: Are you saying that the DOM is rendered when you pause code in a debugger? Or that it does not happen?

Comment: The DOM is rendered when i pause code in debugger. My purpose is prove that `p.textContent` wouldn't be `text` before microtask run.

Comment: `p.textContent = 'text';` does happen before any microtask is even scheduled?

Comment: UI is blocked by JS before JS stack is cleaned up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply prove it by looking at the [event-loop processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model). To paraphrase its current status while omitting the few steps we're not interested in:

- 1. Choose a task to execute
- 5. Execute that task
- 7. Perform microtask end-point
- 11. Update the rendering (if it's time to do so)
- 14. Repeat

So here it's quite clear microtasks are executed before the rendering happens.

Not yet convinced?

Here is a snippet which **will block your UI for 5s** using only microtasks. The page content will not be rendered before this lock is released:

```js
// We wrap our code in a 0 timeout and two rAF levels
// to be sure the initial rendering of the page did occur
setTimeout( () => {
requestAnimationFrame( () => {
  requestAnimationFrame( () => {

    // Now we modify the DOM
    document.querySelector( 'p' ).textContent = "modified";
    // and we start locking the UI using a Promise chain
    const start = performance.now();
    (function lockUI() {     // IIFE
      if( performance.now() - start  < 5000 ) {
        // recursive Promise chaining
        // all these promises will get executed before the next rendering
        // and block the UI rendering
        // even though we were in an rAF callback!
        return Promise.resolve()
          .then( lockUI );
      }
    } )();
    
  } );
} );
}, 0 );
```

```html
<p>Initial (please wait 5s)</p>
```

The careful readers will notice that this script is not even queuing microtasks to the **7**th step of the event loop, but to the **11.12** *interleaved microtask checkpoint*.

This only better cements the point that the actual rendering is only done at step **11.15**, and that anything before can actually delay it.

---

So in your test case, "text" should never be **rendered**, since by calling `Promise.resolve().then()` you actually queue a microtask, which from the event-loop's point of view is actually the same as a synchronous operation here since there is nothing going on after that queuing.
Except that **there is a case** where you could still see the text rendered anyway, which is if the browser enters the [*spin the event loop*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#spin-the-event-loop) algorithm. This may happen if the browser faces a long task and decides it can execute this algorithm, which will allow for the rendering steps to occur even though there is still a long task being ran.
For instance, Firefox does this whenever you initiate modals like `alert()` or `prompt()` etc.

So **in Firefox**, this snippet will actually render the text `text`, Chrome doesn't call this algorithm here, so it won't render anything, not even the initial `test`:

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
p.textContent = 'text';
Promise.resolve().then(function microtask() {
  alert();
  p.textContent = 'Promise';
});
```

```html
<p>test</p>
```

However Chrome **does** call this algorithm with `debugger`. So this keyword will not block the rendering, and that's why you do see `text` being rendered.

Comment: This is my first stackoverflow question and your answer is exactly what i want, thanks a lot !